# Tracking the Number of Image Targets available at the particular moment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Using Vuforia's Unity Extension, I have a strong grip on the basics. But then I stumbled upon [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpNrWKQFq6Q) that shows a really cool feature for AR in Chemistry. I'd like to know how it detects a certain Image Target, and how it is able to animate like that.

I tried to recreate the video and have a `H cards`, and one `O card` on my scene. But I am unable to figure out what to do next.

If I script something it would probably go something like

```
if(TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker.HCard() && 
   TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker.OCard())
{
  //Put in my animation
}
```

But this does not work. Basically, I can't find a single target with that syntax and there's no Vuforia Log on how to do the same.

How do I initialize animation when the two ImageTargets are in close by.

Looking forward to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the idea is to get the objects to move to each other, i don't know if `if(TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker.HCard() && 
   TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker.OCard())` works or not but  you can try giving tags to your objects and using `gameobject = GameObject.Find ("yourtag");` to get instances of them.
you also need to add colliders to the objects and using the `OnCollisionEnter` function in unity you test if the two objects have collided then all you do is

```
H.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (H.transform.position, O.transform.position, 0.1f);
O.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (H.transform.position, O.transform.position, 0.1f);
```

so this way the two objects will move towards each other . Finally when the objects collide meaning `O.transform.position == H.transform.position`
you deactivate the two objects and instantiate a new one
 `O.SetActive(false);
 H.SetActive(false);
NewObj = Instantiate (NewObj, sphere.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;`

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this wasn't my question. I asked how do you  detect more than two ImageTargets. The animation part isn't important, that should be a piece of cake really. But the how to detect when the two ImageTargets are close to eachother to instantiate the animation is my question.

Comment: You can detect if two ImageTargets are close enough through adding a Collider to each ImageTarget and using OnCollisionEnter() function. This is the simplest way, you can also access each GameObject position and compare the Difference in their transform.x if it's equal to a given set value.  But thourgh Colliders is more simple

Comment: OH yea, awesome idea!